# linear transformation problem involving composition

Tags: linear-algebra

If *T* : *V* $\rightarrow$ *W* and *U* : *W* $\rightarrow$ *V* and 0 < dim *W* < dim *V*.
How can I show that UT is an isomorphism? Can it even be an isomorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't be an isomorphism. $T:V\rightarrow W$ then by $rank-nullity$ theorem, since $dim\ V>\ dim\ W$, hence $nullity\ T\geq 1$ $\Rightarrow$ the map is not injective.